# What permissions does an Azure service principal need to call the New-AzSubscriptionAlias PowerShell function?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I'm trying to create subscriptions through an Azure DevOps pipeline on a hosted agent running as a service principal and am receiving the error:

```
New-AzSubscriptionAlias: /home/vsts/work/1/s/Azure.Automation/Subscriptions/Create-AzureSubscription.ps1:190
Line |
 190 |  $subscription = New-AzSubscriptionAlias `
     |                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'
```

How do I grant the service principal the required access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is written [here in Programmatically create Azure subscriptions with the latest APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/programmatically-create-subscription?tabs=rest-getEnrollments%2Crest-EA%2Crest-getBillingAccounts%2Crest-getBillingProfiles%2Crest-MCA%2Crest-getBillingAccount-MPA%2Crest-getCustomers%2Crest-getIndirectResellers%2Crest-MPA#prerequisites)

> You must have an Owner role on an Enrollment Account to create a subscription. There are two ways to get the role:
>
> - The Enterprise Administrator of your enrollment can make you an Account Owner (sign in required) which makes you an Owner of the Enrollment Account.
> - An existing Owner of the Enrollment Account can grant you access. Similarly, to use a service principal to create an EA subscription, you must grant that service principal the ability to create subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a service principal to create a subscription, then you must grant the service principal the [**Azure RBAC owner**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles#azure-roles) role.

You can use the [New-AzRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azroleassignment?view=azps-5.0.0) command to assign the owner role to your service principal.

To specify a **user**, use SignInName or Azure AD ObjectId parameters.
To specify a **security group**, use Azure AD ObjectId parameter. And to specify an **Azure AD application**, use ApplicationId or ObjectId parameters. The role that is being assigned must be specified using the `RoleDefinitionName` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AzureRmRoleAssignment cmdlet to assign that service principal an **Owner** role.

We tracked it down to two missing permissions required by the underlying New-AzureRmRoleAssignment cmdlet that is called by the task -

- The Service Principal (SPN) used by Azure DevOps to connect to your
  Azure subscription requires the Owner role
- The same SPN also requires Read directory data permissions to your
  Azure AD

There is also a 3rd-party  [Azure Role Based Access Control](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-azurerbac) task you could use in your azure devops pipeline.

More step by step tutorial, please refer this blog-- [Service Principal considerations when using Azure DevOps to manage RBAC on Azure Resource Groups](https://medium.com/azure-architects/service-principal-considerations-when-using-azure-devops-to-manage-rbac-on-azure-resource-groups-f9c35f39ded5)