# What should the BillingScope value be when calling New-AzSubscriptionAlias in Azure PowerShell?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

Am trying to use the Az.Subscription module New-AzSubscriptionAlias function found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.subscription/new-azsubscriptionalias?view=azps-5.0.0).
The function requires a -BillingScope value.
Following advice found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/programmatically-create-subscription?tabs=rest-getEnrollments%2Cazure-powershell-EA%2Crest-getBillingAccounts%2Crest-getBillingProfiles%2Crest-MCA%2Crest-getBillingAccount-MPA%2Crest-getCustomers%2Crest-getIndirectResellers%2Crest-MPA#create-subscriptions-under-a-specific-enrollment-account) it shows that the BillingScope should look something like this:

```
"/providers/Microsoft.Billing/BillingAccounts/1234567/enrollmentAccounts/7654321"
```

What should the first and second numbers in that actually be?
I assume the enrollment account part is the GUID ObjectId of an enrollment account.

I was previously assuming the first number was the agreement ID but it doesn't seem to be working. Just continue to get Unauthorised messages even though the service principal used to run the command has enough access as described in another StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64764889/what-permissions-does-an-azure-service-principal-need-to-call-the-new-azsubscrip).

Comment: Hi is there any update on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

See the previous part: [Find accounts you have access to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/programmatically-create-subscription?tabs=rest-getEnrollments%2Cazure-powershell-EA%2Crest-getBillingAccounts%2Crest-getBillingProfiles%2Crest-MCA%2Crest-getBillingAccount-MPA%2Crest-getCustomers%2Crest-getIndirectResellers%2Crest-MPA#find-accounts-you-have-access-to).

You need to send a request to list all enrollment accounts you have access to:

```
GET https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingaccounts/?api-version=2020-05-01
```

You can try it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/2019-10-01-preview/billingaccounts/list).

In the response, you will find the id of the enrollmentAccount. It is actually the **billing scope** value.

The first number is **billingAccounts name** and the second is **enrollmentAccounts name**.

```
"enrollmentAccounts": [
          {
            "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/1234567/enrollmentAccounts/7654321",
            "name": "7654321",
            "type": "Microsoft.Billing/enrollmentAccounts",
            "properties": {
              "accountName": "Contoso",
              "accountOwnerEmail": "kenny@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
              "costCenter": "Test",
              "isDevTest": false
            }
          }
        ],
```

If you cannot find the enrollmentAccounts property, make sure you have followed the [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/programmatically-create-subscription?tabs=rest-getEnrollments%2Cazure-powershell-EA%2Crest-getBillingAccounts%2Crest-getBillingProfiles%2Crest-MCA%2Crest-getBillingAccount-MPA%2Crest-getCustomers%2Crest-getIndirectResellers%2Crest-MPA#prerequisites).

Comment: As of today this is not working. In the response I just get this (enrollmentAccountName not to be found anywhere)

"id": "/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/1234567",
"name": "1234567",